# Bilinear operator norm question.

Tags: functional-analysis

So I wrote this down a week ago and cannot figure out what I was thinking. Not sure if this is correct.

Context we have a bilinear operator $B:X\times Y\to \mathbb{K}$.

Is it true that
$$\sup_{x\in X, y\in Y} \|B(x,y)\|< \infty \implies |B(x,y)|\leq K \|x\|\|y\|$$

So the absolute value is a norm on the reals, complex in one dimension so that's not a problem because the norms are equivalent.

So the implication works for the $x,y$ supremum case. But does it immediately follow for all other $(x,y)$? I cannot remember what I was thinking. Can anyone help?

Comment: You may want to take that supremum for (at most) unit vectors.

Comment: You may want to take the $Sup_{\|x\|=1\|y\|=1}\|B(x,y)\|$.

Comment: @Berci I start with $\sup_{x\in X} \|B_x \| < \infty$ and I want to end up with $|B(x,y)| \leq K \|x\| \|y\|$ for all $x,y$ in $X\times Y$. If I use the supremum over unit vectors wouldn't that ruin my goal? I'm trying to prove that the bilinear operator is bounded. $X,Y$ are banach spaces. I used the uniform boundedness principle to arrive to $\sup_{x\in X} \|B_x \| < \infty$ where $B_x$ is the map where $x$ is kept constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sup_{x\in X, y\in Y} \|B(x,y)\|< \infty \implies B=0$$

Comment: Can you explain why? I don't really understand.

Comment: By linearity. If $|B(x,y)|\neq 0$ then $|B(tx,y)|=|t||B(x,y)|\to +\infty$.